# JENKINS gradle build error with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I am using below configuration and trying to make Jenkins build but I am getting errors.

Note, I am able to make build successfully with command line.

**My PC environments:**

- OS: ubuntu 14.04
- Gradle version: 2.14.1.
- Jenkins version: 2.25
- Java version: java-8-openjdk-amd64

**JENKINS BUILD ERRORS:**

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2322559356105735311.sh
+ cd /home/ekambaramv/Jenkins/workspace/CARMODE_STAR_O-OS/MAIN/
+ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
+ GRADLE_USER_HOME=/home/ekambaramv/Jenkins/gradle-2.14.1/
+ /home/ekambaramv/Jenkins/gradle-2.14.1/bin/gradle clean build

**FAILURE:** Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILUR
```

E

Comment: If possible try in different version(latest) of jenkins. It might have work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with the JNI libary when using Gradle. It's possible you might be using a version of the JNI library that is incompatible with Gradle.

Try going to the site: https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/libnative-platform-jni_0.11-5_amd64.deb.html and downloading the **libnative-platform-jni_0.11-5_amd64.deb** package onto your machine.

You can either open Nautilus and right click the .deb package and select 'Open with Software Install', or you can navigate the command line to the download directory and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ./libnative-platform-jni_0.11-5_amd64.deb
```

Next, check to see if Gradle still gives you the same "Failed to load native library..." error message as before by running:

`gradle --version`

If the problem persists, and you still get the error message, you might want to consider upgrading to a later version of Gradle. I was able to get this working on Gradle 3.2.1, but I know this method isn't always possible.

If you need to back out the changes, just run another `sudo apt-get update`, and the JNI libraries will be overwritten with the latest version once more.

### **One More Thing**

I mentioned the libraries get overwritten the next time you update your system (apt-get, Software Updater). To prevent this, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libnative-platform-jni
```

This will force the update software to overlook any later versions of the library. To turn this off, run the opposite command:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold libnative-platform-jni
```